# Whether $\cos z$ is onto?

Tags: complex-analysis

The question states,

The function $f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is defined by $f(z)=\cos z$ is

A. one-one

B. onto

C. bijective

D. Bounded

How should I check whether this function is onto or one-one. If I see real number, as codomain, then obvoiusly $\cos x$ is not onto as $\cos x$ is bounded between 1 and $-1$.
But this is $\cos z$, can I conclude anything from this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with what the definition of $\cos z$ is for complex $z$. Are there values it cannot hold? If not, can it be bounded? ¶ This definition extends the function from the reals to the complex numbers. Is the function one-to-one (injective) for the reals? Is it bijective for the reals? What does that say about those properties for the complex numbers?

Comment: If it helps, remember $$cos(z) = \frac{e^{zi}+e^{-zi}}{2}$$. What do you think this function gives?

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be one-one, since this is even false when restricted to the real line.
Therefore, it also cannot be bijective. It also cannot be bounded, since then, by Liouvilles theorem, it would be constant. Alternatively, let us show it is onto and therefore unbounded:

Note that for any $w\in \mathbb{C}$, we have
$$
\cos(z)=w \iff e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2w
$$
Substituing $u=e^{iz}$ (which is never zero), we have
$$
u^2+1=2wu.
$$
This something you can solve for a nonzero $u$. Hence there exists a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{iz}=u$, which solves the equation $cos(z)=w$ by construction.

Comment: Your answer could be two sentences since you have already got rid of three of the answer choices and there is one left.

Comment: That would imply that at least 1 is correct. Also, I wanted to give a full answer to maybe help OP how to tackle these problems in the future. Furthermore, my reasoning with Liouvilles theorem might be too advanced at this point.